# Half bones are inverted on armature

Tags: animation, bones

I have this animation that I recovered from an old video game project, when I import the FBX animation on Blender, I have a strange display in which half of the bones are inverted, but the armature is correct, how could I rectify this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your armature? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=WlXrlNvl" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/WlXrlNvl/)

Comment: Is the left part animation correct? I can't tell why your armature has been disorganized, but maybe try to reorganize the bones in Edit mode and see if it works? Even though the rest pose isn't a real rest pose, so I doubt it will work correctly at the end...

Comment: I will try to reorganize that, thank you for your help

Comment: I found a solution by selecting the good oriented bones and use symmetrize in edit mode ! Thank you !

Comment: oh great if it fixed your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by selecting the good oriented bones and use symmetrize in *Edit Mode*.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.